# With OAuth2, should I send the auth code or tokens to the service from a mobile client?

Tags: oauth-2.0

So my understanding of OAuth2 from a mobile client is:

1. Mobile client redirects page to get user auth using client id
2. Resource holder responds back with an `auth_code`
3. `auth_code` is exchanged for an `access_token` and `refresh_token`

In the above, if you have a web service that is acting to support your mobile app, you permanently store the `access_token` and `refresh_token`, which will allow you to continue to access the user's data, provided they haven't revoked your permissions.

So the question I had was: should the `auth_code` be sent to the service, and exchanged there for the tokens? Or should the client exchange the `auth_code`, and send the resulting tokens to the service? Does it not matter, or is it perhaps different for different implementations? I'm assuming the client secret is only stored on the service, and my understanding is that is needed to exchange a `refresh_token` for a new `access_token`, but I wasn't sure about the `auth_code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client secret is needed also when requesting the tokens using the authorization code.

The client can request the tokens directly or delegate that to the service - there is not a hard and fast rule saying you should do one or the other.

I'd say if the service is going to use the tokens probably delegating to the service makes most sense - so the tokens stay there. If the client is going to use the tokens both approaches are valid.

Comment: Ah I see - wouldn't having the client secret on the client be a security risk? My understanding is that was something like a password for your application, which proves you are you.

Comment: Yes, storing the client secret inside the client is a security risk - because you cannot prevent someone to extract it from there, but if you store the client secret on the service then the client can request it and use it - without ever storing it - so as long the communication between the client and the service is encrypted (that should be in any case) security is OK